# How to update QTableView on QAbstractTableModel Change

Tags: python, qt, qt4, qt5

While working with the `QTableView` and `QAbstractTableModel` there are times when the QTableView is not updated with the changes taking place in QAbstractTableModel's data. In order to "enforce" or to trigger the view update I use  QAbstractTableModel's `self.layoutChanged.emit()` method.

While it works I have noticed this method may cause some instability and even a crash. I wonder if there is an alternative way to update the QTableView when the QAbstractTableModel changes?

Comment: you mean a change different from inserting row/column ?

Comment: Exactly. Example: changing the number of columns returned by QAbstractTableModel's `columnCount()` method won't update the QTableView.

Comment: are you already using `insertRows()` with `beginInsertRows()` and `endInsertRows() ` ? otherwise you may try the [dataChanged](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#dataChanged) event

Comment: What is the syntax for `dataChanged`? Please post an example as the answer so we could up vote it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, you can connect a function to the model dataChanged signal/event, or you can insert this signal inside the function used to modify the model if you have implemented one.

The first option could be like below, in your model class,

```
self.dataChanged.connect(self.view.refresh)
```

where refresh() is a custom slot in your view which trigger a simple `self.update()`, otherwise you need to handle the parameters send by the signal (affected parents QModelIndex).

---

The second option needs to emit the signal with QModelIndex, call this in the function when you apply some changes in the model class :

```
self.dataChanged.emit(self.index(X, Y), self.index(X, Y))
```

where X and Y represent the position of the changed data in your table

The third parameter *role* is an option, i.e. you can specify the `DisplayRole`, otherwise all roles can be updated.

Comment: Neither of these methods work. dataChanged has no attribute 'connect' and you can't attach an emit to it.

Comment: @NLee23 please could you submit a new question with your code ?