# How to handle multi-user database interaction with PyQt5

Tags: python, database, ms-access, pyqt5, multi-user

I am developing a GUI app that will be used supposedly by mutliple users. In my app, I use QAbstractTableModel to display a MS Access Database (stored on a local server, accessed by several PCs) in a QTableView. I developped everything I needed for unique user interaction. But now I'm moving to the step where I need to think about multi-user interaction.

For exemple, if user A changes a specific line, the instance of the app on user's B PC needs to update the changed line. Another example, if user A is modifying a specific line, and user B also wants to modify it, it needs to be notified as "already being modified, wait please", and once the modification from user A is done, the user B needs to see this modification updated before he has any interaction.

Today, because of the local nature of the MS Access database, I have to update the table view a lot of time, based on user interaction, in order to not miss any database modification from other potential users. It is kinda greedy in terms of performance and resources.

I was thinking about using Django in order make the different app instances communicate with each other, but maybe I'm overthingking it and may be there is other solutions.

Dunno if it's clear, I'm available for more informations !

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could simply store a "lastUpdated" timestamp on the row. With each update, you update that timestamp.

Now, when you submit an update, you include that timestamp, and if the timestamps don't match, you let the user know, and handle the conflict on the frontend (Perhaps a simple "overwrite local copy, or force update and overwrite server copy" option).

That's a simple and robust solution, but if you don't want users wasting time writing updates for old rows, you could use WebSockets to communicate from a server to any clients with that row open for editing, and let them know that the row has been updated.

If you want to "lock" rows while the row is already being edited, you could simply store a "inUse" boolean and have users check the value before continuing.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when using a MVC pattern (which is what QAbstractTableModel  + QTableView is) the responsibility of updating the view should lie on the model itself. I.e. it's the model that should notify the view that something changed.
It seems that `QAbstractTableModel` has a `dataChanged` signal that gets emitted on data changes.
I suggest you to connect it to your view `refresh` slot as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45359569/how-to-update-qtableview-on-qabstracttablemodel-change).

In this way you avoid the need of another moving part/infrastructure component (django).